# How do I search questions which I posted?

Tags: support, search

I have asked a few hundred questions by now.

I would like to be able to search though only questions which I asked.

Can I do that? How?

Comment: @Jeff Can I make a feature request to be able to search across all sites? I would like to be able to search all of my question titles across all sites as I often can't remember whether I asked on S.O, programmers, Linux, or where. Also, I would like to be able to search all S.E sites for my unanswered questions. Without having to code any scripts myself. Search terms are just about acceptable (if they would work with user name, since user number varies across sites), but, ideally, I would prefer just to be able to click a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the search box with `user:me views:0 <search term>`.

`user:me` -- searches in your own *posts* (questions and answers)
`views:0` -- restricts the search to questions with >= 0 views (somewhat of a hack to restrict to questions, but that's the only way to do it)

For a full list of these options, see the [Search Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=) page, which you can also get to by hitting enter in the search box when it's blank.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend google and your username

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&q=stackoverflow.com+mawg+rad+android&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=ca05a7bb65e82229

Comment: frightening, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed. And easy to use ;)

Answer (score 1):

see

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

and the `user:` operator